# React - Hiding Environment Variables in Production file

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I have a requirement which necessitates me hiding environment variables and not committing them to a git repository.

In ASP.net core for example, we use placeholders:

```
{
   "api-key": [placeholder],
   "another-key": [placeholder]
}
```

In React .env file, can we use placeholders similar to the one above and by running a cmd or powershell script fill them up?

Would this actually work in Javascript? I assume since before bundling everything, all key values should be present and not filled later.

So the final output which I am expecting in .env should look like this:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY = [placeholder]
REACT_APP_ANOTHER_KEY = [placeholder]
```

Then using a cmd or powershell script during the bundling to replace these placeholders with actual values.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, it's actually doable depending on the operating system

Following this [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) instructions.

To set it on Windows (cmd.exe)

```
set "REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=abcdef" && npm start
```

To set it on Windows (Powershell)

```
($env:REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE = "abcdef") -and (npm start)
```

And finally on Linux, macOS (Bash)

```
REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE=abcdef npm start
```

This is what I was looking for.

Comment: The fact that these are in the `.env` is not necessarily hiding them. The variables are still present in your production build and accessible in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can do this during the build process.....
suppose you are creating build using webpack. We can use 'dotenv' for environment variables.

inside your 'webpack.config.js....'

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

module.exports = () => {
    // call dotenv and it will return an Object with a parsed key 
    const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

    // reduce it to a nice object, the same as before
    const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
        // replacing placeholder will be done here....
        if (env[next] === 'placeholder') {            
            prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify("test");
        }
        else {
            prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
        }
        return prev;
    }, {});

    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
        ]
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm using create-react-app, is there a way to extend its webpack settings to do this solution?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired for update webpack settings

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I found a much simpler solution and posted it as an answer :)